# What's the mobile equivalent of DragEvent?

Tags: javascript, mobile, draggable

I made a carousel and my dragevent works fine on computer but doesn't on mobile.

I've seen someone suggest to use touchEvent but touchEvent doesn't work on either.

```
const $img = document.querySelector('img');

$img.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){ console.log(`Start: ${e.screenX}`) },false);

$img.addEventListener('dragend', function(e){ console.log(`End: ${e.screenX}`) },false)
```

if i do the same request using touchstart or touchend i get no value on the event

```
/* event does not fire */
$img.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ console.log(`Evento: ${e.screenX}`) }, false)
```

Comment: Look at [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove)

Comment: touchmove doesn't work for me, needs to be start and end

Comment: `touchstart` and `touchend`?

Comment: touchstart and touchend did not work for me, no value was returned

Answer (score 0):

On mobile, you can use:

- [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart)
- [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove)
- [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)
- [touchcancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchcancel)

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="test">Drag Me!</p>
    <script>
      const p = document.getElementById("test");
      p.addEventListener("dragstart", handleStuff, false);
      p.addEventListener("touchstart", touch2drag, false);
      function handleStuff(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.clientX) {
          console.log(`Stuff happened at ${e.clientX}x;${e.clientY}.`);
        }
      }
      function touch2drag(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        // translate to mouse event
        let clkEvt = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        clkEvt.initMouseEvent(e.type.replace("touch", "drag"), true, true, window, e.detail,
                    e.touches[0].screenX, e.touches[0].screenY,
                    e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY,
                    false, false, false, false,
                    0, null);
        p.dispatchEvent(clkEvt);

        // or just handle touch event
        handleStuff(e);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```